# Unhandled Rejection (SyntaxError): Unexpected end of JSON input with Get request fetch

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, express

I am trying to do a MVC architecture tutorial from Codecademy's website: https://www.codecademy.com/article/mvc-architecture-for-full-stack-app

I finished the tutorial but when I run everything, I get this error:

[image]

It seems that what I'm returning is not valid JSON. So I think the problem is that the endpoint may be causing the error. But I'm not too sure. Here is the code where the error is triggered:

src/utils/index.js:

```
export const fetchExpenses = async (date) => {
 const selectDate = new Date(date).getTime() || new Date().getTime();
 const res = await fetch(`/api/expense/list/${selectDate}`);
 console.log('result',res);
  return res.json();
};
```

Here is the code from app.js in the "view" portion of my code:

```
useEffect(() => {
  // update view from model w/ controller
  fetchExpenses().then((res) => setExpenses(res));
}, []);
```

It seems the problem is the communication between the view and the controller. When I create an expense, it actually is updated in the database:

[image]

Any ideas why this error is happening?

**Edit 1:**

Here is the network response when I try to create a new expense in my application. So it seems that when I create a new expense, the  `fetchExpenses()` is automatically called to display a list of current expenses.

[image]

this the raw response I get from `fetchExpenses()` :
[image]

**Edit 2:**

Here is what the header shows from the response:
[image]

The endpoint is causing the error, but I'm not sure why. Here is the endpoint:

```
export const createExpense = async (data) => {
  const res = await fetch(`/api/expense/create`, {
    method: 'POST',
    body: data,
  });
  return resHandler(res, 201);
};
```

and here is `resHandler()` which `createExpense()` returns:

```
export const resHandler = async (res, status) => {
  if (res.status === status) {
    return null;
  }
  const data = await res.json();
  if (data && data.emptyFields) {
    return data.emptyFields;
  }
  return null;
};
```

Here is the code from the controller when an expense is created:

```
exports.create = (req, res) => {
  const form = new formidable.IncomingForm();
  form.keepExtensions = true;
  form.parse(req, async (err, fields) => {
    const { title, price, category, essential, created_at } = fields;
    // check for all fields
    if (fieldValidator(fields)) {
      return res.status(400).json(fieldValidator(fields));
    }
    try {
      const newExpense = await pool.query(
        'INSERT INTO expenses (title, price, category, essential, created_at) VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4, $5)',
        [title, price, category, essential, created_at]
      );
      return res.status(201).send(`User added: ${newExpense.rows}`);
    } catch (error) {
      return res.status(400).json({
        error,
      });
    }
  });
};
```

**Edit 3**

Here is the route `/api/expense/list/{dateTime}`:

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();

const { create, expenseById, 
    read, update, remove, expenseByDate } = require('../controllers');

router.get('/expense/list/:expenseDate', expenseByDate, read);

module.exports = router;
```

And here is my controllers.js that deal with the route above:

```
exports.expenseByDate = async (req, res, next, date) => {
  try {
    const expenseQuery = await pool.query(
      'SELECT * FROM expenses WHERE created_at BETWEEN $1 AND $2',
      [
        startOfDay(new Date(Number(date))).toISOString(),
        endOfDay(new Date(Number(date))).toISOString(),
      ]
    );
    const expenseList = expenseQuery.rows;
    req.expense =
      expenseList.length > 0
        ? expenseList
        : `No expenses were found on this date.`;
    return next();
  } catch (error) {
    return res.status(400).json({
      error,
    });
  }
};

exports.read = (req, res) => res.json(req.expense);
```

Comment: What's the point of showing the consuming code if the problem is that the response body isn't JSON? Did you look at what it _is_? Examine the _producing_ code?

Comment: What does the network response look like for the /api/expense/list/{date} request in your chrome dev tools?

Comment: Is the response valid JSON? what exactly is being returrned?

Comment: @epascarello I don't think the response is valid JSON. I edited my post to show my network response when the api is called.

Comment: @g0rb I edited my post to show what i receive in my network response

Comment: @vroque2022, the endpoint is likely causing the issue. Can you show the headers from the response and maybe post your endpoint code?

Comment: @g0rb I made another edit to my post to show what happens in the headers from the response. Thanks for your help!

Comment: @vroque2022 can you post the `/api/expense/list/{dateTime}` resource as well?

Comment: Hi @g0rb I made **edit 3** to show the  `/api/expense/list/{dateTime}` resource

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason you are getting an `Unhandled Rejection (SyntaxError): Unexpected end of JSON input` error is because your client app is expecting a JSON response and the express app `/api/expense/list/{dateTime}` route is not returning valid JSON.

The app is not returning valid JSON because the `expenseByDate` controller callback has an incorrect function signature so it is not getting called.

```
exports.expenseByDate = async (req, res, next, date) => <-- "date" is not a valid parameter.
```

This leads the `read` controller to return an undefined value to the json response.

```
exports.read = (req, res) => res.json(req.expense);  <-- req.expense is undefined.
```

`res.json(undefined)` ultimately returns an empty response to the client which can't be parsed and thus an error is thrown.

**Solution**

You can fix this error by correcting the `expenseByDate` controller to have a valid function signature by removing the fourth method parameter. To access a route parameter you should use `req.params`.

```
exports.expenseByDate = async (req, res, next, date) => {
    const date = req.params.expenseDate;
    ...

}
```

Comment: Thank you so much at @g0rb !!I couldn't have solved the issue without your help. All the best :)